# Прокрутка на месте

Tags: javascript, html, css

По примеру с этого сайта https://www.vincit.com/ нужно сделать подобные заглавия. При скроллинге страницы, когда доходим до заглавия (About, Work и др.) прокручиваем колесико раза два и после этого появляется следующий контент. То есть получается эффект будто прокрутка страницы замедляется. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким эффектом либо знает как его реализовать?

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="content">
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="title">
 Title 1
 </div>
 <div class="content">
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="title">
 Title 2
 </div>
 <div class="content">
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В коде с примера используется http://barbajs.org. Может быть легче готовое решение использовать?

Comment: Спасибо, за наводку. Гляну этот скрипт